# How to make contents fit to divs using css

Tags: css

How to make the inside divs fit to the contents in the below html
I tried with display:inline-block but it moves the 2nd div to the bottom.

```html
<div class="ms-table">
  <div class="tableCol-75">
  </div>
  <div class="tableCol-25">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not really enough information.  If one is dropping down and you want them inline, then it's a width problem of some type.  Using inline-block is right, but it won't force them into place if the widths of the children are   more than the parent container allows for.  Check the rules in your css classes.  Look at things like padding.  Also using max-width rather than width will allow them to shrink to fit.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense.  You need to rephrase it or expand on it.  Are you trying to make the two inner divs fit horizontally?  Vertically?

Comment: Make the inside div fit the contents????? Div's automatically expand to fit the content. Clearly need to expand/rephrase question.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```css
.ms-table {
  width: 80%;
}

.tableCol-70 {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.tableCol-25 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;  
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="ms-table">
  <div class="tableCol-70">
    My name is abc and I live in ams.
  </div>
  <div class="tableCol-25">
    I love junk food even though it is unhealthy
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My favorite part of your code is .tableCol-75 with a width of 70%.

Comment: Thanks EduardoFernandes will try this

Answer (score 0):

use `display: table`

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ms-table{    
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
.table-cell{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 15px;
}
.tableCol-75{
    width: 75%;
    background: #ccc;
}
.tableCol-25{
    width: 25%;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="ms-table">
  <div class="table-cell tableCol-75">75%</div>
  <div class="table-cell tableCol-25">25%</div>
</div>
```

use `display: inline-block;`

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ms-table{       
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
}
.table-cell{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 15px;
}
.tableCol-75{
    width: 75%;
    background: #ccc;
}
.tableCol-25{
    width: 25%;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="ms-table">
  <div class="table-cell tableCol-75">75%</div><!--
  --><div class="table-cell tableCol-25">25%</div>
</div>
```